# Xcode will not open my project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I where working with a project and I closed because my computer was geting slow. When I tried to open my solution again xcode quitted. So everytime I try to open my project I get this error:

[image]

I am not able to open my solution. IS THERE A WAY I CAN RECOVER MY PROJECT!?

Comment: I have the same issue. I can access the old account using a 2010 MacBook Pro, running High Sierra, but cannot use a modern Xcode. This is obviously very frustrating.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try, first make sure Xcode is not running ,trash the ~/Library/Cache/ folder contents, and trash the contents of the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ folder, if you what to can just find the stuff for your project in  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and trash just that. Then restart your computer.

If that doesn't work, rename your faulty projects folder to so method like ' old', create a new project of the same name, and then move all of the source files from ' old' to you new project and add them. Its a bit painful I known but I have had to do this once to get a project working again.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! I tried doing the first thing and it did not work :( . But I will try doing your second option.

Comment: when you mean replace the source files you mean all the files except myProjecName.xcodeproj file?

Comment: Yes, you are just creating a new project with the old source files, can Xcode open other projects fine, if not maybe you need to delete Xcode's preferences file.

Comment: BTW, in my 10.8.2 it's plural, `~/Library/Caches`.

Comment: You're awesome, I just trashed the folders you mentioned, and didn't have the patience to restart my computer, and it worked!

Comment: I wish I could vote this up more than once! You saved my project!

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer helps me to solve this. In my case, before this issue happened I changed the `PROJECT_NAME.xcscheme` file externally (from Github desktop). Will it be the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 68):

Nothing mentioned above/below worked for me. Here's what I did instead:

Right click on the `.xcodeproj` file and select *Show Package Contents*. Then delete the `project.xcworkspace` file. Open the project in Xcode and voilà.

Comment: In finder my xcodeproj "file" is a file but in a terminal it is a directory and the workspace file is within that directory that you can remove.

Comment: But I have to delete it every time I open it.

Comment: easy and useful

Comment: This works, but since I'm using Cocoa Pods, I had to do a `pod install` after to recreate the `project.xcworkspace` file.

Answer (score 8):

#### Double click the actual file! NOT the recent item!

Turns out that double-clicking on the actual file instead of selecting it from the *Welcome to Xcode* window will help open the project as expected!

Also, after the first time open it with double-clicking the file, the window will be fixed by itself ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the project was moved to my iCloud Drive without me noticing it.

If it happens to you too, just go to your Finder, locate the project and check if there is a cloud next to it. Just right click it and "Download now". Try again once the download is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with Xcode 12. Opening Xcode, and selecting my project from 'Recent projects' list was causing Xcode to crash

**My solution:** I navigated to the folder and opened ProjectName.xcworkspace file, then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Quit Xcode, then make a copy of the xcworkspace file (just in case). In finder, right-click the xcworkspace file and choose Show File Contents.

In that directory, open the xcuserdata directory and delete any contents. Start Xcode again and open the project.

In my case there was something wrong with the saved project state, so doing this resets the state and it opened normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with git, right click the `project-name.xcodeproj > Show Package Contents`, open the file `project.pbxproj` and check for conflict and resolve it.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error and none of the above helped me.

Solution that helped me: Create a new project, then without closing it, go to

> File -> Open

and select your .xcworkspace file.

Comment: Please use snippet to explain, so any newcomer will easily understand