# Flutter Project Xcode File corrupted

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter project with an Xcode file. I woke up this morning and it suddenly just stopped working.

I tried opening the xcode project file with xcode and that's when I realised that it's corrupted. It won't open, I'd get the spinning raindbow wheel whenever I click on it while other projects open instantly.

The .xcodeproj file doesn't open while the .xcworkspace file opens but xcode shows that it keeps loading the project i nfinitely.

I have the project and it's history on a private github repo but looking at the changes the xcode project files haven't changed.

I tried deleting the project and then cloning it again but that didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Edit: I also tried `flutter clean` but it just loads forever and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the podfile and then creating it again

Here is what I usually do:

1. go into `ios` folder
2. delete the `Podfile.lock` file
3. `rm -rf Pods`
4. `pod cache clean --all`
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod setup`
7. `pod install`

You may also want to do

```
pod repo update
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did this and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/14748832/15782390. I think your answer also would have worked.